# LottieView doesn't update the animation after changing the filename state variable in swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

what i want to achieve is

When i double tap on the view, the lottie animation should change with a random animation name in an array.
Here i am changing the the observable name variable successfully.

but it doesnt update the lottieview with new animation.

I am sharing my code here.

```
    import SwiftUI
import Lottie

struct VerseView: View {
    
    @State var lottieName = "3"
    var verse:Verse!
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           
            LottieView(animation: .named(lottieName))
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .containerRelativeFrame([.vertical])
                
            VStack {
                Text(verse.title)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .bold()
                
                Text(verse.desc)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                
            }.padding(30)
            
        }
            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                
                
                lottieName = "1"
                print("lottie name is \(lottieName)")
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    VerseView(verse: verses[0])
}
```

When i print the state variable called lottieName, it prints it with changed lottieName.

But still the lottieview doesnt get updated.

Someone point a solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide `reloadAnimationTrigger` to reload the animation, and also a valid load Animation closure for `LottieView`. Try this:

```swift
LottieView {
    LottieAnimation.named(lottieName)?.animationSource
} placeholder: {
    Text("Loading...")
}
.playing(loopMode: .loop)
.reloadAnimationTrigger(lottieName, showPlaceholder: true)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: even the lottie team never mentioned this anywhere...thanks a lot mann...works like charm